# I'm trying to install PostgreSQL onto Ubuntu 14.04, but I am having difficulties after following a guide

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, installation

I originally followed the guide at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime.html.  It instructed me to install postgres-xc, which is meant for making clusters of databases.  On other sites, I was instructed to use the postgres-9.3 package (or 9.x) instead of the postgres-xc package.  One inconsistency I noticed was that arguments such as `--nodename` [were missing from the original guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/server-start.html), which led me to believe there was an issue with the original guide

I have uninstalled postgres-xc using both `apt-get remove --purge postgres-xc` and `dpkg remove --purge postgres-xc`, as advised by others, as well as following [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/274536/257226), which involves changing  `postgres-xc.prerm` so that it exits early on.

Additionally, I have uninstalled and reinstalled the postgresql-package many times and also run `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib` and `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3`.  I have done this after uninstalling other version.  When I try running the `postgres` command in Bash, I get the following error:

> The program 'postgres' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt-get install postgres-xc

I've been trying to get this to work for a while, but nothing has worked so far.  The only binary for PostgreSQL I can use is `psql`, which is just a dynamic session for it (and I want to set up a server).

Comment: Why do you want to run the command postgres? To start the server use the command `service`, to connect to the database use `psql`. The documentation in the PostgreSQL website is not meant to be used with packages installed via distribution package managers, since distributions have their own methods.

Comment: if you have mlocate installed try locate pg_ctl and add the path to it to your $PATH

Comment: You have an option to use [the graphical installer from EnterpriseDB.](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload)